# display output of a method in action class into a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I have a method in my action class where I execute a command and I need the output of that command to be displayed on a **JSP page**. How do I do that please advise.

Below is the command that i am executing in the method:

```
Process pr = rt.exec("java  weblogic.Admin -url server_name:port_num -username user -password  
             passwd CLUSTERSTATE -clusterName clu");
```

The output of the above command I want to display in JSP page called status.jsp, please help me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 1.5, the javadoc says : *As of 1.5, ProcessBuilder.start() is the preferred way to create a Process*. But it is still fine to use `Runtime.exec()` ...

You first have to collect the output of the command ... without forgetting the appropriate charset (for example `String charset_name = "ISO-8859-1";` or `IBM850` or ...) :

```
Reader rd = new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream(), charset_name);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] buffer = new char[1024];
int len;
while ((len = rd.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        sb.append(buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

Then, you have just to put the content of the `StringBuilder` in a request attribute if you run the command in a servlet (and you should do for ease of test ...), forward to the servlet and use the string:

```
request.setAttribute("CMD_OUTPUT", sb.toString());
```

If you run the command from the JSP with a scriptlet, simply do `out.print(sb.toString());`

Edit:

If you run the above outside the JSP, and put the result in a request attribute as shown above, you can access to it in the JSP for example that way :

```
<jsp:useBean id="CMD_OUTPUT" scope="request" class="java.lang.String"/>
<p>Result of command : ${CMD_OUTPUT}</p>
```

Comment: I am getting an error in the out.print statement. Cannot be resolved error.

Comment: @user1795999 please give some context around the error, what you try to print, where it comes from,...

Comment: @user1795999 : Sorry, but I can't help you without some context, whether you used a scriptlet or a servlet, full text of error (or stacktrace), ...

Comment: i used scriptlet like this:
<% out.print(sb.toString());%>
i am getting a redline under sb saying sb cannot be resolved and a syntax error on the semi colon saying delete this token.

Comment: Do you call the `Process pr = rt.exec(...); ...` in same JSP, or do you save the result in a request attribute ?

Comment: i call the process in action class in a method,and i read the output of the command using readline and store it in a variable called line and do request.setattribute in the action class.

Comment: Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
{
Process pr = rt.exec(""+ command +" && "+ admin +" && java weblogic.Admin -url "+ server +":"+ port +" -username "+ user +" -password "+ passwd +" CLUSTERSTATE -clusterName "+ clu +"");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
String line=null;
while((line=input.readLine()) != null) 
{
System.out.println(line);
}}}finally{
}}else { 
System.out.println("no app selected");
}}}}catch(Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.toString());
e.printStackTrace();
}}

Comment: the output of the command is stored in the line variable, pls help me how to display this output in jsp page.

Comment: In my answer, I concatenate what is read from command (you `line` variable) in a `StringBuilder` and then put **that** in a request attribute. At the end of you loop `line` is null (it is the condition to end the loop) ! See my edit for detail on how to use it from the JSP

Comment: I dont see any edits could you please post the code here